# Replace string using regular expression in KETTLE

Tags: regex, kettle

I would like to use regular expression for replacing a certain pattern in the Kettle. For example, AAAA >5< BBBB, I want to replace this with AAAA <sub>555</sub> BBBB. I know how to find the pattern, but I am not sure how to replace that with new string. The one thing I have to keep is that I have to find pattern together ><, not separately like > or < because there is another pattern <5>.

Comment: You'd have to isolate `xx>5<xx` from `<5>`. In other words, what separate's `<5>5<5>` ? You'd need to know that `xx>5<xx` is unique. Like `(\D)>(\d+)<(\D)` giving the three groups needed to do the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Replace in String" step in a transformation.

Set use RegEx to "Y", type your regex on the Search box, with capturing groups if necessary, and the replacement string in the replacement box, referring to capture groups as $1, $2, ...

It'll replace all occurrences of the regex in the original string.

If the Out Stream field is ommitted, it'll overwrite the In stream field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pattern `>\d<` replaced by a triple of the found digit, you can use Replace-In-String in regex mode:

```
Search:     (.*)(>(\d)<)(.*)
Replace:    $1$3$3$3$4
```

If you want all such patterns treated the same:

```
Search:     (>(\d)<)
Replace:    $2$2$2
```

EDIT due to your improved requirement

Since you intend to convert your "simple" markup to a more HTML-like markup, you better use a User-Defined-Java-Expression. Also, you must avoid to reintroduce simple markup when replacing repeatedly.

[image]

Comment: Could I ask the meaning of (.*)?

Comment: What I want to do is to replace > with <sub> and < with </sub>. For example, >3< should be replaced with <sub>3</sub>. Any characters can be put in the '3' position.