# Delete portions of a string using regex in PDI KETTLE

Tags: regex, string, kettle, pdi

I'm trying to clean a string with "Replace in string" step in PDI KETTLE.

The input string looks like this:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; mso-ansi-language: ES"> AAA <p></p></span></p> <p class="MsoNormal" style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; mso-ansi-language: ES"> BBB <personname w:st="on"> CCC.
```

The desired output would be to delete string portions between every '<' and '>' chars, to get this:

```
AAA  BBB  CCC.
```

Looking for similar questions, I tried with this one [Replace string using regular expression in KETTLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280581/replace-string-using-regular-expression-in-kettle)

In a "Replace in string" step, I use RegEx, search for (<(.*)>) and nothing to replace with.

But the problem is that it deletes everything bewteen the first '<' and the last '>' chars, and the output is:

```
CCC.
```

How should I build the RegEx expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `(.*)` is greedy, therefore it'll capture everything up to the last `>`.

To make it lazy you can either:

- Make your quantifier lazy, by using `(<(.*?)>)`
- explicitly set the class of characters you want to capture, `(<([^>]*)>)`

Either should work and produce as output

```
 AAA   BBB  CCC.
```